# Google maps 100vh not working on Android app tablets only

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

```
#map-canvas {height: 100vh; width: 100vw;}

<ion-view title="Truck Map">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-content>
        <div data-tap-disabled="true">
            <div id="map-canvas"></div>
        </div>
        <button id="map_refresh_btn" class="button icon ion-refresh button-positive" ng-click="refreshMap()">
              Refresh
        </button>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Here is the css and html I use in my angular / ionic / cordova android and ios apps.  For some reason I have yet to figure out, android tablets are not able to display the google map with this css, although it works fine on all iOS devices and all Android phones.  The map displays if I give it a specific height and width in pixels, but this is not a flexible solution.  Any help as to the cause or a fix would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The implementation for iOS (7 at least) for vh is also not working properly. I solved the whole situation just by making a good guess for fixed height in CSS and then resolving the real height with JavaScript. Here's something that could solve your issue as well: https://github.com/rodneyrehm/viewport-units-buggyfill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the parent div is defaulting to a size of 0, causing the child div with map-canvas id to also have no size, causing the map not to be displayed.

```
<div data-tap-disabled="true">
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</div>
```

It doesn't seem like you utilize the parent div for anything except the tap attribute.  Why don't you try joining the 2 divs into 1 and keeping your css the same?

```
<div id="map-canvas" data-tap-disabled="true">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cordova Android makes use of the WebView component supplied by the operating system. You've got to make sure that your tablet's Android version is supporting viewport units:

- http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

You can help yourself with absolutely positioning the map and setting it to 100% height.

Alternatively you can migrate your Cordova Android project to CrossWalk WebView which is supporting viewport units. Ionic CLI makes this relatively easy:

- http://ionicframework.com/blog/crosswalk-comes-to-ionic/

Comment: `#map-canvas {position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; }`  Changing the CSS to this or excluding width did not solve the problem.  Any other suggestions?  Thanks.